# Stored procedure to determine if failure has occured

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am running SQL Server on Azure.  I have a table that I store the failure rate and count for each region and channel that I monitor.  If any region/channel go above 2% failure rate and the count is more than 5 for three consecutive days, I need to adjust my sample rate from 5% to 7.5%.  I tried to use an average but that does not give me the results correctly if I have a big count for two days and then a small count.

I tried to use the average failure rate and average failure count for the last three days but that does not work.  For instance:
12.57% and 20 count
10.25% and 4 count
10.71% and 3 count

Even though the rate is above 2% the count did not go above 5 for three consecutive days.  But if you take the average, then you get this –

11.17% and 9 count which is a false condition.

Table -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dfc_LoanRateRecords](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [usOnlineRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [usOnlineCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [usRetailRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [usRetailCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cdnOnlineRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [cdnOnlineCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cdnRetailRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [cdnRetailCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ukOnlineRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [ukOnlineCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ukRetailRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [ukRetailCount] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.dfc_LoanRateRecords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Current stored procedure -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dfc_sp_average_loan_failure]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   
             (CASE WHEN AVG(usOnlineRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(usOnlineCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)      AS usOnlineRate
            ,(CASE WHEN AVG(usRetailRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(usRetailCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)      AS usRetailRate
            ,(CASE WHEN AVG(cdnOnlineRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(cdnOnlineCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)    AS cdnOnlineRate
            ,(CASE WHEN AVG(cdnRetailRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(cdnRetailCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)    AS cdnRetailRate
            ,(CASE WHEN AVG(ukOnlineRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(ukOnlineCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)      AS ukOnlineRate
            ,(CASE WHEN AVG(ukRetailRate) > 2.00 AND AVG(ukRetailCount) > 5 THEN 7.5 ELSE 5.0 END)      AS ukRetailRate

    FROM dfc_LoanRateRecords
    WHERE rateDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, -3, GetDate()) and GetDate()
```

Data -

```
Id  rateDate    usOnlineRate    usOnlineCount   usRetailRate    usRetailCount   cdnOnlineRate   cdnOnlineCount  cdnRetailRate   cdnRetailCount  ukOnlineRate    ukOnlineCount   ukRetailRate    ukRetailCount
2   2016-02-22 00:00:00.000 0   0   12.57   20  0   0   0.2 2   0   0   0   0
3   2016-02-23 00:00:00.000 0   0   10.25   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   2016-02-24 00:00:00.000 0   0   10.71   3   0   0   0.64    1   0   0   0   0
5   2016-02-25 00:00:00.000 100 2   2.27    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   2016-02-26 19:53:53.080 100 2   6.97    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   2016-02-29 17:28:00.887 100 2   7.33    11  3.84    3   0   0   0   0   5.88    1
9   2016-03-01 12:19:02.377 20  1   3.44    2   0   0   0.22    1   0   0   0   0
10  2016-03-02 11:09:17.773 100 2   6.87    9   0   0   0.34    1   0   0   0   0
11  2016-03-03 13:23:38.397 100 2   12.32   9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  2016-03-04 17:43:37.600 100 3   13.25   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  2016-03-04 17:45:25.053 100 3   13.25   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  2016-03-07 15:48:32.167 100 4   8.43    14  4.76    3   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Could you please show some data and your wrong result?

Comment: you have to check the condition in every row right?